# Jenkins Cannot deploy to artifactory (database constraint error)

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I am using Artifactory  OSS v4.5.1, Jenkins v1.648, Gradle v2.9, on Ubuntu 14.04

I am using artifactory plugin for jenkins v2.4.7 to deploy an artifact generated by gradle build script

When I run gradle artifactoryPublish by hand, everything is ok, but when i try to deploy from jenkins, the jar file deploys fine, but the build info cause an error

here is jenkins console output:

```
Jenkins Artifactory Plugin version: 2.4.7
Jenkins Artifactory Plugin version: 2.4.7
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[workspace] $ gradle jar artifactoryPublish
[buildinfo] Properties file found at '/tmp/buildInfo1752901429055581915.properties'
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication
:artifactoryPublish
Deploying artifact: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/gradle-local/org/commerceforge/estore/0.0.1/estore-0.0.1.jar
Deploying build descriptor to: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/build
Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under http://localhost:8081/artifactory/webapp/builds/Tradenity/21

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 11.237 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS
Deploying build info to: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/build
ERROR: Could not publish build-info: Failed to send build descriptor : HTTP response code: 500. HTTP response message: Internal Server Error
java.io.IOException: Could not publish build-info: Failed to send build descriptor : HTTP response code: 500. HTTP response message: Internal Server Error
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.sendBuildInfo(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:244)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericBuildInfoDeployer.deploy(GenericBuildInfoDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator$1.tearDown(ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator.java:344)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:173)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILURE
```

when i refer to artifactory log, it seems like a database eror:

```
2016-03-01 12:05:22,150 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:453) - Deploy to 'gradle-local:org/commerceforge/estore/0.0.1/estore-0.0.1.jar' Content-Length: 0
2016-03-01 12:05:24,120 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [INFO ] (o.a.r.r.c.BuildResource:296) - Adding build 'Tradenity #22'
2016-03-01 12:05:24,302 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [INFO ] (o.a.r.r.c.BuildResource:313) - Added build 'Tradenity #22'
2016-03-01 12:05:24,686 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] [INFO ] (o.a.r.r.c.BuildResource:296) - Adding build 'Tradenity #22'
2016-03-01 12:05:24,749 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] [ERROR] (o.a.r.c.e.GlobalExceptionMapper:46) - Could not insert build Build{version='1.0.1', name='Tradenity', number='22', type=GENERIC, buildAgent=Generic/Generic, agent=hudson/1.648, started='2016-03-01T12:05:06.642+0200', durationMillis=18018, principal='anonymous', artifactoryPrincipal='admin', artifactoryPluginVersion='2.4.7', url='http://localhost:8088/job/Tradenity/22/', parentName='null', parentNumber='null', vcsRevision='7fdaa715b604d2a27eed956af5560a06a1d6ebe8', vcsUrl='null', parentBuildId='null', licenseControl=org.jfrog.build.api.LicenseControl@399632b2, buildRetention=org.jfrog.build.api.BuildRetention@26e7505f, runParameters=null, modules=[org.jfrog.build.api.Module@39c3f4dc], statuses=null, buildDependencies=[], issues=null, governance=org.jfrog.build.api.Governance@533a0edd}
org.artifactory.storage.StorageException: Could not insert build Build{version='1.0.1', name='Tradenity', number='22', type=GENERIC, buildAgent=Generic/Generic, agent=hudson/1.648, started='2016-03-01T12:05:06.642+0200', durationMillis=18018, principal='anonymous', artifactoryPrincipal='admin', artifactoryPluginVersion='2.4.7', url='http://localhost:8088/job/Tradenity/22/', parentName='null', parentNumber='null', vcsRevision='7fdaa715b604d2a27eed956af5560a06a1d6ebe8', vcsUrl='null', parentBuildId='null', licenseControl=org.jfrog.build.api.LicenseControl@399632b2, buildRetention=org.jfrog.build.api.BuildRetention@26e7505f, runParameters=null, modules=[org.jfrog.build.api.Module@39c3f4dc], statuses=null, buildDependencies=[], issues=null, governance=org.jfrog.build.api.Governance@533a0edd}
    at org.artifactory.storage.db.build.service.BuildStoreServiceImpl.addBuild(BuildStoreServiceImpl.java:122) ~[artifactory-storage-db-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.build.BuildServiceImpl.addBuild(BuildServiceImpl.java:193) ~[artifactory-core-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor375.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.artifactory.storage.fs.lock.aop.LockingAdvice.invoke(LockingAdvice.java:76) ~[artifactory-storage-common-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.addBuild(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.artifactory.build.BuildServiceImpl.addBuild(BuildServiceImpl.java:172) ~[artifactory-core-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor374.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.artifactory.storage.fs.lock.aop.LockingAdvice.invoke(LockingAdvice.java:74) ~[artifactory-storage-common-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.addBuild(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.artifactory.rest.resource.ci.BuildResource.addBuild(BuildResource.java:305) ~[artifactory-rest-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor373.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$VoidOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:167) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.execute(RepoFilter.java:198) [artifactory-web-application-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.doFilter(RepoFilter.java:89) [artifactory-web-application-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.useAuthentication(AccessFilter.java:334) [artifactory-web-application-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.authenticateAndExecute(AccessFilter.java:234) [artifactory-web-application-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessFilter.java:190) [artifactory-web-application-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:156) [artifactory-web-application-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:65) [artifactory-web-application-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryFilter.java:109) [artifactory-web-application-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.22]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.22]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'BUILDS_NAME_NUMBER_DATE_IDX' defined on 'BUILDS'.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.storage.db.util.JdbcHelper.executeUpdate(JdbcHelper.java:160) ~[artifactory-storage-db-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.storage.db.build.dao.BuildsDao.createBuild(BuildsDao.java:65) ~[artifactory-storage-db-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.storage.db.build.service.BuildStoreServiceImpl.addBuild(BuildStoreServiceImpl.java:119) ~[artifactory-storage-db-4.5.1.jar:na]
    ... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'BUILDS_NAME_NUMBER_DATE_IDX' defined on 'BUILDS'.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.IndexChanger.insertAndCheckDups(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.IndexChanger.doInsert(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.IndexChanger.insert(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.IndexSetChanger.insert(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.RowChangerImpl.insertRow(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.InsertResultSet.normalInsertCore(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.InsertResultSet.open(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.executeStmt(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    ... 83 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I can't verify it at the moment, but might this be related to the "Capture Build Info" functionality of Artifactory Plugin. Do you have it enabled? Also not sure if "build info" works with Artifactory OSS.

Comment: The answer is right there in the log: `Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'BUILDS_NAME_NUMBER_DATE_IDX' defined on 'BUILDS'.
`
It is related to the build info (which does work with OSS) as you suggested - it looks like an existing build number is being deployed again - is your jenkins build not incrementing build numbers?